# What is the probability that a hypothesis test fails?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, information-theory, kullback-leibler, probability-inequalities

If $X\sim P$, given some other distribution $Q\gg P$ what is known about $\mathbb{P}(P(X)< Q(X))$, i.e. the probability the outcome was more likely to have come from $Q$?

In particular are there any bounds on the quantity in terms of statistical distances?

Comment: What does the double greater than sign mean?

Comment: $P\ll Q$  means $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$, which means that "all the events $Q$ says have probability 0, $P$ also says have probability 0." It's so that the ratio $P(X)/Q(X)$ makes sense.

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the body seem like pretty different questions. Also, I'm not sure what the notation $P(X)$ or $Q(X)$ mean; I'm not even sure whether $P$ and $Q$ are supposed to be PDFs, CDFs, probability measures, or something else.

Comment: The probability I am asking about is precisely "given $X$ came from $P$, what is the probability the outcome is more likely to have come from $Q$" which due to Neyman-Pearson is the most powerful hypothesis test for some significance level. The question only makes sense as stated if $P,Q$ are pmfs on finite alphabets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general PMFs $P,Q$ with $X\sim P$ then nothing interesting can be said about $\mathbb{P}(P(X)<Q(X))$ for all the metrics I know about:

Imagine $P(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ for $x\in[1:n]$, 0 otherwise, and $Q(x) = \frac{1-\varepsilon}{n-1}$ for $x\in [1:n-1],$ $Q(n)=\varepsilon$ and 0 otherwise. For $X\sim P$, then $\mathbb{P}(P(X)<Q(X))=1-\varepsilon-\frac{1}{n}$, even though all these distance metrics go to 0:

- $\|P-Q\|_1\approx 2/n$,
- $\|P-Q\|_2\approx \frac{1}{n\cdot (n-1)}$ and
- $D(P\|Q)\leq \log(\frac{n-1}{n})-\frac{1}{n}\log(\varepsilon n)$.

[With slight adjustment, the following holds in general](http://www.public.asu.edu/~cdchapm2/bounding-false-distribution-probability/index.html) (follows easily by expanding it into an integral of an indicator function):

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{P}(P(X)<c\cdot Q(X)) \leq c.
\end{align}